# Python While Loop with Characters

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need help being able to print characters (ex:*) in a while loop with a certain number of that character. 
ex:

```
>>>printTriangle(4)
*
**
***
****
>>>printTriangle(3)
*
**
***
>>>printTriangle(6)
*
**
***
****
*****
******
>>>printTriangle(0)

>>>
```

what i have right now is

```
def printTriangle(Tri):
    asterik="*"
    total=asterik*Tri
    while total!=0:
        print(total)
```

and this just causes an infinite loop. can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to modify total inside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You get an infinite loop cause total never gets 0.
But you don't need `while`, try with for:

```
def printTriangle(x):
    for i in range(x+1):
        print '*'*i
```

If you want to use `while` something like this will work:

```
def printTriangle(x):
    total=1
    while total!=x+1:
        print '*'*total
        total+=1
```

Example:

```
>>> printTriangle(4)
*
**
***
****
```

Comment: the only problem is that I'm required to use `while` loops for more practice with it

Comment: @Dolan, ok! Updated using while. The mistake in your code is that the while loop never gets terminated so you get an infinite loop. Hope it helps...